# inserting into database returns empty?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problems with inserting into a database. the query completes successfully but when I look in the database the fields are empty.

Here's my HTML form:

```
<form action = "add_at.php" method = "post">
    <input type = "text" class = "userip" name="userip">
    <input type = "text" class = "coordinates" name="coordinates">
    <input type = submit>
</form>
```

Here's my php script:

```
<?php

$mysql_host ='host';
$mysql_user ='user';
$mysql_pass ='pass';
$mysql_database = 'database';
$user_ip = $_POST['userip'];
$user_cords = $_POST['coordinates'];

mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) or die('unable to connect.');
mysql_select_db($mysql_database);
$query = "INSERT INTO `userips` (ip,cord) VALUES ('$user_ip','$user_cords')";

mysql_query($query) or die('nope, sorz.');
mysql_close();

echo('woot wooooooooooooot')

?>
```

**Update:**

I found the problem.
I needed to add a \ to one of my input fields in my HTML form.
Simple mistake. Thank you all for your help, though.

Comment: How do you know the query completes successfully? You are doing nothing to check the result. You are also doing absolutely nothing to protect yourself against SQL injection.

Comment: Is there actually any value in $_POST? var_dump it, tell us... And tell us some more!

Comment: It might be because of datatype mismatch. If you try to insert a value into a field in different type than the data, it may insert a blank record.

Comment: There is value in the $_POST, and I know it has completed because an empty record appears in my database

Comment: You should REALLY consider to sanitize your data, in order to prevent SQL-injection.

Comment: Do protect against attacks, especially against SQL-Injection, please review OWASP's PHP security summary: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check to see if your post variables are set before calling your SQL command.

Eg...

```
if (isset($_POST['userip']))
```

Also, you are open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Try `mysql_error()` after your query. I think you have an SQL-Error in your query. And you should really have a look at SQL-Injections.

```
mysql_query($query) or die('nope, sorz.');
echo mysql_error();
mysql_close();
```

Edit:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `userips` (ip,cord) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($user_ip)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($user_cords)."')";
```

Comment: There isn't an error, it just inserts an empty record into my database.

Comment: Then your POST variables are not set.

Comment: I found the problem.
I needed to add a \ to one of my input fields in my HTML form.
Simple mistake. Thank you all for your help, though.